# What recourse is there for a refused proposed edit that is sorely needed?

Tags: discussion

I am told this is the place to find help in a situation where a user refused an edit that should not have been refused:

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18986

What recourse do I have here?

The moderator appears to be powerless to even express support for the edit and rebuffed my pursuit of a resolution in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In this particular case your "pursuit of a resolution" that I rebuffed (and deleted the relevant comments in response to community flags) was obnoxious and possibly insulting to the original poster. If you want to make progress on issues like this toning down your comments would go a long way.
2. In this particular case your edit is not "sorely needed". Personally I agree it's an improvement and would have approved the edit, but lets face it: some white-space and  two minor wording changes that may or may not reflect the OP's intent is not a desperate scenario. *"[...] forever a blemish [...]"* Methinks thou dost protest too much.
3. In this particular case your edit included multiple wording changes. It's not uncommon for an OP to disagree with one of them and reject and edit that also included more palatable changes. I wouldn't have done this differently, just keep it in mind when wondering why something might have gotten rejected.
4. In general not every OP understands the function of the site very well either and some might reject something accidentally because they didn't understand what was going on or what they should do about it. In these cases if an edit that is an obvious improvement fails, I would suggest a (polite) comment explaining what the issue is and how it could be improved.
5. At some point you have to move on. Not all users are going to agree with you and unless something is actually against site guidelines, at the end of the day the person who posted usually has the most say in the matter. If you think the current form is poor content then downvote and move on.

Comment: My "obnoxious" comment was "Did someone refuse my edit??". But okay, since pursuing the matter thusly is unacceptable I will down vote and move on.